# How is the value of the _doc parameter determined in Elasticsearch? Is it ordered based on insertion?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, nosql

I want to be able to control the order of the _doc parameter across all my documents. Is there a way to do this? Do I have to re-insert all the documents in my database?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that.

Roughly speaking, yes, it will *tend* to sort on insertion order, but that is not a guarantee, and you should never rely on that sort staying the same. Like _score, _doc is not actually a field. It is lucene's internal document id. It can change without notice, and there is no way to explicitly set it's value. You should *only* sort on it when you don't care about the order.

If you want to have a value to sort your documents in a predictable fashion, you will need to index a field with that value.